# I am looking for a formula to give certain results

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

If I knew the name of the formula, it'd be easy to just google it and find out.
However, I don't and I count on you, mathematicians to give me a hand in this.

Let's say we have two constants

```
x = 4
y = 6
```

and a 3rd variable "`z`" that could be between 4 and 6. I am looking for the percentage `z` is from `y` assuming that if `z` is 4 it is 0%.

I need to use such a formula to calculate intervals in a game I am supposed to make. If the boundary was 0 - 6 it couldn't have been easier - `z * 100 / y`, but it is 4 - 6.

Comment: How about: $(z-y)/y$, the arithmetic return, is the relative change in percentage. If $z=4$ its $0$ percent, if $z=6$ its $50$ percent, etc.

Comment: So you want $z=4$ to mean 0% and $z=6$ to mean 100%? You can use $$\frac{z-4}{6-4} = \frac{1}{2}(z-4)$$

Comment: @Bungo that's right. And z = 5 to mean 50% respectively.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Nope, because z = 5 is 25% in this case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the percentage is $\frac{z-x}{y-x}\cdot 100$

Comment: That works. :) What is this called anyways?

Comment: There is no specific name for this formula. If you are given a problem like this, you might want to first draw a picture of the line containing $x$, $y$ and $z$, and then use basic algebra skills to find the formula.

Comment: @Edenia It's a special case of [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)

Comment: I see. Thanks, guys. I used to figure out things like this by myself with diagrams and basic algebra skills, but my brain got lazy or something.